# Get all DistributionGroups and Members that have contacts with a specific domain

Tags: powershell, email, exchange-server

I have an 0365 environment, I want to get all distribution groups and the members that match a specific "domain"

My below code works but I have to specify the distribution group name

`Get-DistributionGroupMember "DG Name" | Get-MailContact | select primarysmtpaddress, alias | where-Object {($_.primarysmtpaddress -like "*@domain.org.au*")}`

I dont know all DG names that match my criteria how can I modify my code to run through all of them

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Get-DistributionGroup` cmdlet to get a list of all Distribution and mail-enabled Security groups. Then loop through that list.

If you don't want to include the securitygroups, filter these out like below

```
$saveto = "C:\file.csv"
Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited | 
    Where-Object { $_.GroupType -notlike '*SecurityEnabled'} |   # filter out mail-enabled security groups
    Get-DistributionGroupMember | 
    Get-MailContact | 
    Where-Object { $_.primarysmtpaddress -like "*@domain.org.au*" } |
    Select-Object PrimarySMTPAddress, Alias |
    Export-Csv -Path $saveto -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Comment: I can not for the life of me indent code block but yes thank you. I also figured it out after some trial and error. Your way seems very clean

Comment: Thanks. You may consider accepting one of the answers, so other people wit a similar question can find it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer id did it

$saveto = "C:\file.csv"

Get-DistributionGroup | sort name | ForEach-Object {

```
"`r`n$($_.Name)`r`n=============" | Add-Content $saveto
Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.Name | sort Name | where-Object {($_.primarysmtpaddress -like "*@domain.org.au*")}| ForEach-Object {
            $_.Name + " (" + $_.PrimarySMTPAddress + ")" | Add-Content $saveto
        
}
```

}